# Drools access object inside HashMap while iterating

Tags: java, oop, hashmap, drools

I have added an object from a user defined class into a HashMap. When inserted into Drools code, I can iterate through the HashMap and get the key and value pair. But I cannot access the attributes inside the user class which is the value section of the HashMap.

This is the POJO file used to hold data. This POJO will be inserted to the LinkedHashMap with a separate key. Currently, this key is just being generated using a simple for loop.

```
package com.sample.pojos;

import java.util.Date;

public class DateSet {

public DateSet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
}

public DateSet(String trainingType, Date completedDate, Date expirationDate) {
    super();
    this.trainingType = trainingType;
    this.completedDate = completedDate;
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
}

private String trainingType;
private Date completedDate;
private Date expirationDate;



public String getTrainingType() {
    return trainingType;
}
public void setTrainingType(String trainingType) {
    this.trainingType = trainingType;
}
public Date getCompletedDate() {
    return completedDate;
}
public void setCompletedDate(Date completedDate) {
    this.completedDate = completedDate;
}
public Date getExpirationDate() {
    return expirationDate;
}
public void setExpirationDate(Date expirationDate) {
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
}




}
```

This is the Java code used to add values to the LinkedHashMap. I have used LinkedHashMap because I need to access the items in the correct order. The key of the HashMap is an int while the value will be a DateSet object.

```
outHash.put(incrementedId, new DateSet(training.getTrainingType(), training.getCompletionDate(),
                    training.getExpirationDate()));
```

This is the Drools rule that I'm using to handle the HashMap. The commented part in the code is how I would like to use the object inside Drools. " entry.getValue()" prints the DateSet object but I cannot access attributes inside it.

```
rule "Validate test"
agenda-group "validate_init"
    when
        someClass: SomeClass($tMap : outHash)                       
        entry : Entry($valueV : value) from $tMap.entrySet()  

        //Boolean(booleanValue == true) from ($valueV.getTrainingType() == "NEW")       

    then
    //System.out.println($valueV.getTrainingType());
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "-" + entry.getValue());
 end
```

Comment: I am able to print the DateSet object using $valueV as well. But I cannot access the attributes still...

Answer (score 3):

This rule does what I think you want (version 6.3.0):

```
rule "Validate test"
when
    SomeClass($tMap : outHash)                       
    e: Map.Entry(k:key, v:value) from $tMap.entrySet()
    DateSet( tt: trainingType == "NEW" ) from v 
then
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + "-" + tt);
end
```

However, one wonders why you didn't insert the DateSet object as individual facts, which makes accessing and filtering quite easy. The artificial numbering (incrementedId) isn't part of the data, so what's its purpose?

**Edit**
If you need to compare one DateSet object with the next (in sort order by date) you should add an ordinal attribute to DateSet and insert the DateSet objects. Then:

```
rule "check for overdue training"
when
    $ds1: DateSet( $ord1: ordinal, $exp: expirationDate )
    $ds2: DateSet( ordinal == $ord1+1, completedDate > $exp )
then
    // ds2 is too late
end
```

The trick her is that the attribute `ordinal` enables you to select successive pairs of DateSet objects (as they were created and numbered ordered by date): it compares the first with the second, the second with the third, and so on. - You can add `trainingType == "NEW"` or similar for further selection.

Comment: No i have to compare the expirationDate of the key value pair with the completedDate of the next pair while iterating. I assumed it would be easy to handle this if it was in an object. Any thoughts on how to do the comparison? Much appreciated @laune

Comment: Example comparison would be like "is the gap between the expiration date of this key value pair and the completed date of the next pair, more than 2 years?" @laune

Comment: So the original training objects are in ascending date order, which also puts the DateSet objects in the same order? -- Added a way to compute (what I understand) you want to do.

Comment: Yes. I am sorting the HashMap in correct date order before sending it into Drools.. @laune

Comment: Can u explain what this new rule does? @laune Thanks a bunch anyway. I should be able to pass the respective dates to a drools function or whatever now I hope. With the ordinal

Comment: I've added a sentence or two to explain the logic.

Comment: UPDATE: Is there a way I can declare global variables inside Drools and then access them from Drools functions? I can access without any issue from the rules but not from functions. @laune